# How to create a custom file input in Ionic 2+ with a button styling?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

Here is my template:

```
<label>{{label}}</label>
<input type="file" (change)="fileUpload($event)" id="file-input" style="position:absolute; top: -999999px" #fileInp>
<button ion-button (click)="onClick()">Upload</button>
```

and the ts file:

```
@ViewChild('fileInp') fileInput: ElementRef;
@Input() label: string;
@Output() data = new EventEmitter<FormData>();

fileUpload(event) {
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', event.srcElement.files[0]);
  this.data.emit(fd);
}

onClick() {
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Everything works fine on Android and in the browser, but not on iOS.
The same code works if I disable the button in the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't trigger the click on a file input on iOS. A workaround is to use css to set the opacity of the input element to 0, and place it just on top of the button. That way, the file input won't be seen, but it will be clicked when clicking the button.

```
<ion-item>
  <label>{{label}}</label>
  <input type="file" (change)="fileUpload($event)" id="file-input" style="opacity: 0" #fileInp>
  <button ion-button (click)="onClick()">Upload</button>
</ion-item>
```

and then in the .scss file:

```
#file-input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

There're probably some other ways to fix this issue, but that's how I managed on an app I worked on in the past.

Answer (score 5):

I usually do the following.

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-button color="primary" (click)="inputFile.click()">
             <ion-icon name="attach"></ion-icon> Anexar documentos
        </ion-button>
        <input #inputFile id="input-file"  style="opacity:0" type="file" (change)="uploadFiles($event)"
        multiple/>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to do it is use a label with the `for` attribute and customized it using css. So when the user clicks on the label, the input is triggered. Keep in mind that the `for` label must be the input id.

```html
<label class="myFakeUploadButton" for="myFileInput">Upload</label>
<input type="file" id="myFileInput">
```

```css
#myFileInput{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.myFakeUploadButton{
 /* Whatever you want */
}
```